# haskell, why does head' function okay in ghci but cannot be compiled?

Tags: haskell

```
head' :: [a] -> a
head' [] = error "Cannot call head on emply list."
head' (x:_) = x 

main = do  
    putStrLn  "hello"
    let ret = head' [4,5,6]
    putStrLn ret
```

Above code, I can load it in ghci and call head' function correctly.
When I put it into a file and try to compile it. IT thows error.
I cannot figure out why is that. need help;
thanks.

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( head.hs, head.o )

head.hs:7:22:
    No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal `4'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num String)
    In the expression: 4
    In the first argument of head', namely `[4, 5, 6]'
    In the expression: head' [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`putStrLn` takes a `String` (its type is `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`), not a numeric type. What you want is `print`

```
    ...
    print ret
```

`print` can take any type that has a `Show` instance. Its type is `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`